# Significato di "donarsi agli altri"

Tags: meaning

Buongiorno,

Qual è esattamente il significato dell'espressione "donarsi agli altri"?
Vorrei sapere esattamente quali atti artistici potrebbe comportare questo tipo di donarsi. Si tratta forse di atti fatti con il corpo, doni e regali, offerte di informazioni su cose che si sanno, ecc.?

Sarei grato se qualcuno potesse chiarire più concretamente quest'espressione "donarsi agli altri".

Grazie.

Answer (score 6):

In senso proprio, *donarsi agli altri* indica atti di altruismo compiuti di persona (non, quindi, dando denaro, ma mettendo a disposizione il proprio tempo, o donando letteralmente parti del proprio corpo):

[image: donazione di midollo]

È una locuzione più forte che *dedicarsi agli altri*; quando doni qualcosa, l'oggetto donato è di proprietà del ricevente, che ne fa ciò che vuole. Per questo il termine ha una forte connotazione religiosa (Lettera di S. Paolo Apostolo ai Galati: *"Vivo nella fede del Figlio di Dio, che mi ha amato ed **ha donato se stesso per me**"*).

Se si parla di *atti artistici*, per esempio una *performance*, di solito si usa la locuzione *offrirsi agli altri*, quasi a indicare che ciò che è dato agli altri non è "tolto" a chi lo dà; o esplicitamente *offrirsi alla vista degli altri*. Ma è una distinzione abbastanza sottile.

Answer (score 3):

In genere viene usato per atti di forte altruismo come ad esempio dedicare buona parte del proprio tempo ad aiutare le persone povere o malate. Viene spesso usato in ambito religioso.

Answer (score 3):

Sarei grato se qualcuno **potesse**!

"Donarsi agli altri" significa donare le proprie risorse (tempo, energia e denaro) ad altre persone.

> Si tratta forse di atti fatti con il corpo?

Non necessariamente. Vedi sopra.